# I tried to make connection for Google BigQuery in java, and get following error?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

**//error-**

Not Found

Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 404 Not Found

at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:209)

at BigQuerySample.main(BigQuerySample.java:25) */

**// this is my code**

```
            import com.google.api.client.googleapis.*;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.clientlogin.*;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.*;
    import com.google.api.client.http.*;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class BigQuerySample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    HttpTransport transport = GoogleTransport.create();
    transport.addParser(new JsonCParser());
    try {
        // authenticate with ClientLogin
        ClientLogin authenticator = new ClientLogin();
        authenticator.authTokenType = "ndev";
        authenticator.username = "*********@gmail.com";
        authenticator.password = "**********";
        authenticator.authenticate().setAuthorizationHeader(transport);

        // make query request
        HttpRequest request = transport.buildGetRequest();
        request.setUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v1/query");
        request.url.put("q","SELECT TOP(word, 50), COUNT(*) FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare");
                    System.out.println(request.execute().parseAsString());

                } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.response.parseAsString());
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're querying a URL that doesn't exist. Going to [that URL](https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v1/query) returns "Not Found" which is what the exception is telling you. Use a valid URL and then see if your code works (there may be absolutely nothing wrong with your code).

Answer (score 0):

Google BigQuery doesn't support ClientLogin auth. Where did you get that sample?

Comment: check out this link. form here i found this sample program..

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/ClientLogin#Sample_Program

if you have any solution then let me know ? Thanks

Comment: If you notice, that's under "legacy and deprecated methods". ClientLogin isn't a supported way of doing auth for BigQuery. You'll need to use OAuth2. See https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization